# Odoo 11 user cannot create new contact despite extra permissions set

Tags: permissions, odoo-11

I'm running Odoo 11.0 CE 20180126.

Normal users get an error when trying to create a new partner under contacts, telling them that they need to be admin.
The extra permissions to create contacts are set, the buttons appears and the form can be called. But the below error message immediately pops up.

[image]

Weirdly enough users can edit existing contacts but not create new ones.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an interaction with another module which restricted the access. Solution was to remove the unused module.